# Find all elements that DON'T have specific CSS class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have already find a lot of questions like this here in Stack Overflow but none help me.

***My Elements are added dynamically by Ajax.***

When I try to find all elements that don't have specific class, it return the element ho has.

Take a look:

[image]

As you can see, it returns the last element, ho has the div with class `btn-group`.

I want all elements that don't have this div inside.

Comment: You're getting what you asked for `:not()` applies to the element you've attached it to. none of those tds have the `btn-group` class. you need to check for CHILD elements, e.g. `td#xSeleciona *:not.btn-group`

Comment: People down-voted my question, but what's wrong with? Please, at least leave a comment.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa Could you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: @RashminJaviya I was creating one, but our friend `undefined` already find the problem and give me a solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs must be unique. You should use classes instead.

That being said, your selector returns all the elements that have `xSelectiona` ID, `not` method filters the selected elements in the collection not their descendants.

It seems you are looking for the `:has()` selector.

```
$('td.xSelectiona').not(':has(.btn-group)');
```

The above snippet selects all the elements with class of `xSelectiona` that don't have `.btn-group` descendant.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In one of the attempts I put this "id" without paying attention. The trick then is this `:has`. Thank you. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

uses of id is wrong. id must be single.

id instead of class and edit your jquery code such : $('.xSelectiona').not(':has(.btn-group)');

Comment: You're right my friend. Sorry for this "stupid" mistake. In one of my attempts i put this "id" without paying attention.